# Classifying (and solving) a linear, first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, problem-solving

In my work, I've come up with a PDE of the following form:

$$\partial _xV(x,y) = ia \ (y  A(x)) \left( V(x,y) - B(y) \right)$$

where: $a>0$, $x \in [0,L]$, $y \in [0,\infty]$. The $A(x)$ may be approximated by a step function ($1$ for $x < L/2$, $0$ otherwise), and $B$ is a known smooth function.

I've had very little experience with PDEs before and I can't seem to classify this equation. I'd appreciate any help with that as well as hints on how to proceed in solving it.

Comment: It's not really a PDE. The only derivative is in the $x$ variable, so you can treat this an a first-order linear ODE with $x$ as the independent variable. Such ODEs can be solved using an integrating factor or variation of parameters.

Comment: @GyuEunLee But the $y$ dependence is important. I don't want to lose it, which I would if I just treat it like a parameter...

Comment: I think you can keep the $y$ dependence if you integrate correctly. When you integrate in $x$, you will get not an constant of integration, but an arbitrary function of $y$ that replaces the integrating constant. (e.g. $\int 2xy~dx = x^2y + \phi(y)$.)

Comment: Stupid question: what is $\,i\,$ in $\,ia$ ? Is it the complex unit?

Comment: yes, $V$ is complex valued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial V(x,y)}{\partial x} = ia y  A(x) \left( V(x,y) - B(y) \right) \tag 1$$
First, solve the associated homogeneous equation :
$$\frac{\partial W(x,y)}{\partial x} = ia y  A(x) W(x,y) $$
$$W(x,y)=f(y)e^{iay \int A(x)dx}$$
where $f(y)$ is any differentiable function.

Second, solve for $g(x)$ the inhomogeneous equation (1) with $V(x,y)=g(x)W(x,y)$
$$V=g(x)f(y)e^{iay \int A(x)dx} \quad\to\quad \frac{\partial V(x,y)}{\partial x}= g'(x)f(y)e^{iay \int A(x)dx}+g(x)iayA(x)e^{iay \int A(x)dx}$$
Putting it into eq.(1) leads to :
$$g'(x)f(y)e^{iay \int A(x)dx}= iayA(x)B(y)$$
$$g'(x)=ia\frac{yB(y)}{f(y)}e^{-iay \int A(x)dx}$$
$$g(x)=ia \frac{yB(y)}{f(y)} \left( \int e^{-iay \int A(x)dx} dx +F(y)\right)$$
The general solution of eq.(1) is :
$$V(x,y)=ia yB(y)e^{iay \int A(x)dx} \left( \int e^{-iay \int A(x)dx} dx +F(y)\right) $$
where $F(y)$ is any differentiable function.

Since $A(x)$ is a step function, $\int A(x)dx$ has a nice closed form and the above form of solution can be simplified. I suppose that you can take it from here.